# Unable to fetch the specific element value using jsonpath node js library

Tags: node.js, jsonpath

I'm trying to fetch the value of element based on it's value in the complex JSON file.

Trying to fetch the value attribute (Which is 100) if the **currency ='BRL'** and **the index will be subject to change so I just want to try with condition based.**

I just tried below so far:

**Script:**

```
function test()
{
   var result = jsonpath.query(payload,"$..client_balance[?(@.type == 'AVAILABLE')]");
   console.log(result);
}

test();
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    amount: { currency: 'BRL', value: '100', skip: false },
    type: 'AVAILABLE'
  },
  {
    amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '10', skip: false },
    type: 'AVAILABLE'
  }
]
```

Now, I just wanna fetch the value attribute (Which is 100) if the **currency code = 'BRL'**. I tried to apply the [?(@.currency == 'BRL')]
in the tail of the path variable but it returned empty array.

can someone help me to solve this problem.

**Updated:**

Tried filter function to get the specific element value.

```
console.log(Object.values(payload).filter(element =>{
    element.currency === 'BRL';
   }));
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

Comment: Have you tried using double equal `[?(@.currency == 'BRL')]` ?

Comment: Yep. I tried that and It returned empty array.

Comment: Sorry. i think it should be `[?(@.amount.currency == 'BRL')]`

Comment: @Andy - I tried below code to fetch the value of currency code to BRL using filter but it's not working. Since the payload is more complex and it contains nested array. So thought to pick the jsonpath approach. Updated question with filter function results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a complex query, but it should get you what you're looking for.

Start with what you have, which returns the result set you posted:

```
$..client_balance[?(@.type == 'AVAILABLE')]
```

Add to this another filter which looks inside the `amount` field at the `currency` field for the comparison:

```
$..client_balance[?(@.type == 'AVAILABLE')][?(@.amount.currency === 'BRL')]
```

This should give just the one element:

```json
[
  {
    amount: { currency: 'BRL', value: '100', skip: false },
    type: 'AVAILABLE'
  }
]
```

From here you want to get the `value` field, but to get there, you need the path to it, meaning you have to go through the `amount` and `currency` fields first.

```
$..client_balance[?(@.type == 'AVAILABLE')][?(@.amount.currency === 'BRL')].amount.currency.value
```

This should return

```json
[
  100
]
```

---

Please note that we are [working on a specification for JSON Path](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base).  If this library chooses to adhere to it once published, the `===` will need to change to a `==` as this is what we've [decided to support](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/issues/64#issuecomment-830010778).

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(Object.values(payload).filter(element =>{
   return element.amount.currency === 'BRL';
}));
```

I think this should work

Comment: It returned below error. Root cause the JSON file is more complex one and it needs to start from the root element using jsonpath.   TypeError: Cannot read property 'currency' of undefined
    at C:\Users\arrchana\Documents\folder\**\Test.js:11:27
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at test (C:\Users\arrchana\Documents\folder\**\Test.js:10:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arrchana\Documents\folder\**\Test.js:16:1)

Comment: there might be few items which don't have amount object at all. in that case you can try 
return (element.amount && element.amount.currency === 'BRL');

Comment: Let me check this out..!